# Parameterized RMarkdown does not filter parameter in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, parameterized

I am testing to use parameterized RMarkdown, using c as a parameter. I am using `Knit with parameters` choosing `a` or `b`, or nothing which by default chooses `a`.
I expect to obtain 2 or 5 as the mean but I always obtain 3.5 which is the global mean.
What am I doing wrong here?

````
---
title: "Parameterized RMarkdown"
output:
  html_document: default
params:
  c: "a"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
```


```{r mean, echo=FALSE}
df <- tibble(c = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
             x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
mean(df$x)
```
````

Comment: Where are you `filter`ing the `df$x` is extracting the whole column 'x'

Comment: I thought that using a parameter filters. c: "a"

Comment: You need to use `params$c` in your code. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-use.html

Comment: Consider using `df %>% filter(c == params$c) %>% summarise(x = mean(x))`

Comment: (To look at this a different way ... think about a somewhat complex rmarkdown document with several datasets and several params. Would you trust `shiny` to know exactly where you intend to use a param and where to not use it? I've used params as a way to filter/modify a dataset in one code-block and then another code-block I don't use the param. Even though the authors of `shiny` are really smart people, I know of no way to correctly *infer* what and where params are intended to be used.)

Comment: I understand. But in the documentation I never saw an example using params$filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add a `filter` on the extracted 'params'  and get the `mean` of the column 'x'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(c == params$c) %>%
    summarise(x = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or use `base R` to do this

```
with(df, mean(x[c == params$c], na.rm = TRUE))
```